# Recursive delete linked list

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I'm new to programming and I'm having issues with deleting a linked list recursively.

```
int main(void)
{
    node *head = NULL;
    head = push_f(head);
    head = push_f(head);
    head = push_f(head);

    print(head);

    delete_l(head);
    print(head);
}

void delete_l(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    delete_l(head->next);
    free(head);
}
```

It however only seems to delete the last 2 nodes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRYn2.jpg)

Comment: What do you expect from the second `print(head);`? Hint: `head` was freed.

Comment: Well, I'd expect random spaces in memory but it still prints all the nodes except the last 2 making me think the list was not deleted.

Comment: _I'd expect random spaces in memory_. Do not expect any observable behaviour, passing/reading a freed pointer is UB.

Comment: Cleaning up a linked list should not be a recursive operation. Typically you should use something like: if linked list is not empty, remove the first node, then delete the removed node, repeat until list is empty. That makes the operation a clean and simple loop without having to worry to blow up the stack if the linked list is very long.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you David and Cheatah. I was confused about what to expect after the free function but now it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

After calling the function `delete_l`

```
delete_l(head);
```

the pointer `head` in `main` was not changed because the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer. So it still points to the deleted first node of the list.

The function indeed freed the allocated memory. And the next call of the function `print`

```
print(head);
```

just invokes undefined behavior by accessing the freed memory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was indeed confused as to what to expect after the free() function. Now it's clear.

Comment: @Noobster You can select the best answer. In this case your reputation will be increased.:)